# How to UPDATE "key" in JSONB array in PostgreSQL DB

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I want to update the JSONB array in PostgreSQL DB but most of the solutions I'm getting are for updating values adn NOT keys. My target is to change the key "SpindSpeed_Med" to "SpindleSpeed" and "RapidOveride_Med" to "RapidOverride".

Query to make sample database:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    uid int,
    tooldata jsonb
);

INSERT INTO test (uid, tooldata) 
VALUES (1, '[
  {
    "Ftn": 1,
    "SpindSpeed_Med": 1234,
    "RapidOveride_Med": 100
  },
  {
    "Ftn": 2,
    "SpindSpeed_Med": 1234,
    "RapidOveride_Med": 100
  },
  {
    "Ftn": 3,
    "SpindSpeed_Med": 1234,
    "RapidOveride_Med": 100
  }]'),
(2, '[
  {
    "Ftn": 1,
    "SpindSpeed_Med": 1234,
    "RapidOveride_Med": 100
  },
  {
    "Ftn": 2,
    "SpindSpeed_Med": 1234,
    "RapidOveride_Med": 100
  },
  {
    "Ftn": 3,
    "SpindSpeed_Med": 1234,
    "RapidOveride_Med": 100
  }
]');
```

^*Updated for multiple rows and added uid*

Expected result:

```
[{"Ftn": 1, "SpindleSpeed": 1234, "RapidOverride": 100}, 
{"Ftn": 2, "SpindleSpeed": 1234, "RapidOverride": 100},
{"Ftn": 3, "SpindleSpeed": 1234, "RapidOverride": 100}]
```

I have tried using "jsonb_set" but that only changes the value part not the key. Also, I used a combination of "jsonb_object_keys" and "jsonb_array_elements" but that gave just keys as result and I could not put it back into the array. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
select jsonb_agg (q2) from (
  select json_agg(
    j::jsonb - 'SpindSpeed_Med' ||
    jsonb_build_object('SpindleSpeed', j->'SpindSpeed_Med')
  )
from (
    select jsonb_array_elements(tooldata) as j from jsontest
) as q) as q2 ;
```

First, split jsonb array to rows, remove 'SpindSpeed_Med', add 'SpindleSpeed' for each row and finally combine back to jsonb.

Comment: Thanks! But the result I'm getting it putting everything in just one row. How should I get it in the same format as before. I have updated the SQL query for multiple row data now.

Comment: Don't you have any kind of primary key in your table? Add it to the query and `GROUP BY` it

Comment: Here is working complete solution:

WITH temptable AS (
 SELECT 
 "uid", 
 jsonb_agg(elements::jsonb - 'SpindSpeed_Med' || jsonb_build_object('SpindleSpeed_Med', elements->'SpindSpeed_Med')) AS "tooldata"
FROM 
 (SELECT 
 "uid", 
 jsonb_array_elements(test."tooldata") AS elements
 FROM "test" AS test) AS aliasname
 GROUP BY "uid"
)

UPDATE "test" AS te
SET "tooldata" = temptable."tooldata"
FROM temptable
WHERE te."uid" = temptable."uid"